# What is the height of a complete binary tree with N nodes?

Tags: c, linked-list, height, nodes, binary-search-tree

What is the height of a complete binary tree with N nodes? I'm looking for an exact answer, and either a floor or ceiling value.

Comment: log(n). why dont u good first? there is zillion of answers for this

Comment: Your answer is not even correct. If there is a complete tree with 7 nodes, log(7) = 0.84509804001 while the height of that tree would have to be 2. Unless I am mistaken, please explain why it is log(n)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's `CEIL(log2(n+1))-1`

- 1 node gives log2(2) = 1
- 3 nodes gives log2(4) = 2
- 7 nodes gives log2(8) = 3
- 15 nodes gives log2(16) = 4
  ...

EDIT: According to wikipedia, the root node (rather un-intuitively?) does not count in the height, so the formula would be `CEIL(log2(n+1))-1`.

Answer (score 14):

You do not have to do a CEIL(log2(n+1))-1.

For a COMPLETE binary tree, the answer is simply:
FLOOR(log2(n))

- 1 node gives 0
- 2 nodes gives 1
- 3 nodes gives 1
- 4 nodes gives 2
- 5 nodes gives 2
- 6 nodes gives 2
- 7 nodes gives 2
- 8 nodes gives 3
- ...
- 15 nodes gives 3
- 16 nodes gives 4
- ...

Comment: The better way to present this is to say that mathematically ceiling(log(n+1)) -1 is same as floor(logn). Thus the answers of Kelvin and Joachim Isaksson are both correct.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use the formula offered by Joachim or simply do floor log(h)... that is the best case you can do for any binary tree... thus if you tree for example is full you would not be able to say that this is necessarily true ... Also remember that in CS pretty much every log you encounter is of base 2

Answer (score 0):

N is the number of nodes, h is the height of a complete binary tree:
    2**h <= N < 2**(h+1)
=>  h <= ln2(N) < h + 1 // See floor definition in wikipedia
=>  h = floor(ln2(N))

The first inequality represents the fact the number of nodes of a complete binary tree with height h is superior to the number of nodes of a complete binary tree with height (h - 1) and at the same time is inferior to the number of nodes of a full tree with a height h, plus 1. Here is the math:
N_FULL_TREE(h - 1) = 1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2**(h - 1) = 2**h - 1
N_FULL_TREE(h) = 1 + 2 + 4 +... + 2**h = 2**(h + 1) - 1
=> N_FULL_TREE(h - 1) < N_COMPLETE_TREE(h) <= N_FULL_TREE(h)
=> N_FULL_TREE(h - 1) + 1 <= N_COMPLETE_TREE(h) < N_FULL_TREE(h) + 1
=> 2**h - 1 + 1 <= N(h) < 2**(h + 1) - 1 + 1  
=> 2**h <= N < 2**(h+1)